# Printing out LaTex style code from Python

Tags: python, latex

I am trying to print out to a file from python so that I can immediately copy and paste the output into WinEdit to make a tabular.

Example of current code is as follows:

```
sys.stdout = open('C://...', 'w')
for i in xrange(len(freq)):
    if freq[i] > 3725.90649 and freq[i] < 3725.94165:
        print '{:>2}  {:>1} {:>23} {:>1} {:>9} {:>12} {:>10}{:>3}{:>12}'.format(1, "&", "3725.90649 - 3725.94165", "&", freq[i], "$\rightarrow", Tline[i], J_i[i], ")$ \\ \hline")
sys.stdout.close()
```

I want to get the output:

1 & 3725.90649 - 3725.94165 & 3725.9194 $\rightarrow R_{+}^{-}(3.5 )$ \\ \hline

But instead I get this:

1  & 3725.90649 - 3725.94165 & 3725.9194  $ightarrow R_{+}^{-}(3.5 )$ \ \hline

What is going on in the code? How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape all your `'\'` characters with another slash like `'\\'`

```
>>> print '\right'
ight

>>> print '\\right'
\right
```

Or use raw strings (use a leading `r`)

```
>>> print r'\right'
\right
```

Comment: So I just need to add an extra '\'?And what do you mean by "escape"?

Comment: Some string sequences are treated as special characters, and you need to "escape" them to treat them as normal strings. You can read more about that in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

Comment: Note that in this example I showed, I am escaping the special character `'\r'` which is a carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also use [raw string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l) by prepending your string with r

```
print (r"\\ \hline")
```